# Why this div is hidden untill I scroll a litle bit?

Tags: css, html, hidden

EDIT: It's fixed.

I'm creating website: http://mamgrow.lt

The thing is that at the right side "Naujienos" is only appearing when I scroll the page. When I refresh the page it is gone again and it's not appearing untill I scroll a bit.

quick html scheme of it:

```
<div>  //relative
    <div>
        <div class="Naujienos"></div> //relative
    </div>
</div>
```

For more you can check website at the top of post. Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `position:absolute` for

```
<div class="konteineris2">
....
</div>
```

in the css file `bazinis.css`

Comment: Well the position: relative; has set the element according to the other elements in the page, and the div with class 'turinys1' was above it it the html, so that was being displayed first, and this one was under it initially, but on scroll it was changed to absolute from a script you have there and re-assumed the desired position. I hope my explanation is not confusing :)